# Shiv'a Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *azara* of the second *bes hamikdash*, not including the *ezras nashim*, totaled 187 cubits in length. Source: *mishnayos Midos* 5:1.

Answer (score 2):

There are 187 chapters (*p'rakim*) in *Chumash*.

Answer (score 1):

*M'sushelach* had *Lemech* at 187. Source: [*B'reshis* 5:25](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%94).

Answer (score 1):

*Achashverosh*'s two parties, combined, were 187 days long. Source: [*Ester* 1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%90):3–5.

Answer (score 0):

> On Wednesday the 20th October, 2010
>   the National Council of Young Israel
>   (NCYI) and the International Young
>   Israel Movement - Israel Region
>   (IYIM) will proudly donate a Sefer
>   Torah to the I.D.F for the 187th time,
>   over the past twelve years.

http://www.youngisrael.org/pages/index.cfm//187th-Torah-Dedicated-by-Young-Israel-to-the-IDF?printIt=Print

Comment: Other answers in this series of questions have been dependent on currency: "there are currently _n_ years since..." was one answer (I forget what number it was). Is this answer the same: there have to date been 187 donations? Or is the answer merely that at some point there were 187?

Comment: The latter, apparently: http://www.youngisrael.org/pages/index.cfm/188th-Torah-Dedicated-by-Young-Israel-to-the-IDF